# How to custom memory allocator for a static library writen in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator, allocator

To count the memory usage of a static library A, we will write a custom memory allocator or rewrite operator new/delete.

Since there are other libraries in the application, we only want the usage of A. How to achive our goal? Is an allocator or new/delete enough?

Answer (score 1):

Overloading the new and delete operators on the base class will take care of the derived classes as well as this example shows.

This is the base class

```cpp
class Test {
public:
    void* operator new(size_t size);
    void operator delete(void*);
    Test() { cout<<"Constructor called" << std::endl; }
    ~Test() { cout<<"Destructor called" << std::endl; }
};
```

The overloaded operators:

```cpp
void* Test::operator new(size_t size)
{
    cout<<"Operator new called size:" << size << std::endl;
    void *storage = malloc(size);
    return storage;
}

void Test::operator delete(void *p )
{
    cout<<"delete called" << std::endl;;
    free(p);
}
```

Then we define a derived class for the test with an integer inside to make it bigger.

```cpp
class Derived : public Test {
    int value;
};
```

The test then we create one of each object.

```cpp
int main()
{
    Test* test = new Test;
    Derived* derived = new Derived;
    delete test;
    delete derived;
    return 0;
}
```

And it results in the expected behavior

```
Program stdout
Operator new called size:1
Constructor called
Operator new called size:4
Constructor called
Destructor called
delete called
Destructor called
delete called
```

Compiler explorer link: https://godbolt.org/z/sbhdhbsfr

Comment: This leaves out array allocation (new[]), and allocations via allocator by container classes. Also any scaler or array allocations of basic types (can't replace global new as that would also affect the non-library code). Also any unlikely use of malloc or possibly usage of classes from another library. This is going to be a pain, if it is even possible. How much of a pain depends on the nature of the library & how it was written.

Comment: Does anybody use array allocations anymore?

Comment: It should be rare in new code, but we have no idea what the library is like. Also there are frequent posts here that do use them (mainly from people trying to learn C++).  Yesterday, I had the task of sorting out an issue with some seriously old code.